# monetization methods for adobe AIR mobile apps

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder, flex4.6

I am developing android apps usin adobe flash builder with sdk 4.6. can anyone please tell me what are monetization methods I can use apart from Admob.
I used to use airpush and startapp with android sdk. Is it possible to use them with adobe mobile development ? I could not find any native api available for them .

Also, Please tell me what is the miniumn android version that is supported with adobe sdk 4.6 ? does it support android 2.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

There are [Adobe AIR native extensions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/using-ane-in-flash.html) available for in-app purchasing through Google and also Amazon